# Rd2pdf - special (and German) characters

Tags: r, latex, tex, pdflatex

Yesterday I used Rd2pdf to convert the documentation of my R package to pdf and I discovered that special characters like '§' and the German *umlauts* (ä, ö, ü) were not displayed.
I'm using Debian 7 and have a TexLive installation - so for Latex documents I use packages like 'ngerman' to display special German characters like *ä, ö , ü* and *ß*.
So, as Rd2pdf uses the whole latex thing, my question is:

Is there a way to include these additional packages to enable Rd2pdf displaying these special characters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works on my Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf --encoding=UTF-8 file.Rd
```

See the command-line help text

```
R CMD Rd2pdf --help
```

> ...
>
> The Rd sources are assumed to be ASCII unless they contain \encoding
>   declarations (which take priority) or --encoding is supplied or if
>   using package sources, if the package DESCRIPTION file has an Encoding
>   field. The output encoding defaults to the package encoding then to
>   'UTF-8'.

Comment: Thanks, never thought it would be so easy!